# Is $ P_{2}(X_{T}=y|X_{T-\tau}=x)=P_{2}(X_{\tau}=y|X_{0}=x) $?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose that $X=(X_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ and $Y=(Y_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ are two independent homogeneous Markov chains on the state space $S=\{0,1\}$, with transition probability matrices $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ given by

$$P_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1-\theta&\theta\\\theta &1-\theta
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}
\theta&1-\theta\\1-\theta &\theta
\end{bmatrix},$$

where $\theta\in [0,1]$ is a known constant.

Suppose $T$ is an almost surely finite stopping time with respect to the filtration generated by the $X$ process. Then, by the strong Markov property, we know that for any fixed constant $\tau>0$,

$$ P_{1}(X_{T}=x'|X_{T-\tau}=x)=P_{1}(X_{\tau}=x'|X_{0}=x) $$
for all $x,x'\in S$.

However, I am not quite sure if the same property is true with $P_{2}$ as well. In other words, I am not sure of the validity of the above equation with $P_{1}$ replaced by $P_{2}$.

Can anyone kindly let me know how I can evaluate 
 $$ P_{2}(X_{T}=x'|X_{T-\tau}=x)$$
for all $x,x'\in S$?

Any hints or suggestions are most welcome.